# Combine multiple search fields in swift

Tags: swift, search, filter, contains

I have four fields which has to searched and filtered.I am able to search it individually but now i want to combine all 4 fields and get the result and then reload the collection view.

The datamodel used is as follows:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Empty
struct SearchDataModel: Codable,Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: SearchDataModel, rhs: SearchDataModel) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    let status: Int
    var data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable,Equatable {
    let userID: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String?
  //  let image: JSONNull?
    let userAddress: String?
    let id: Int
    let listingImage: String?
    let listingVideo: String?
    let listingTitle: String
    let listingAddress: String?
    let listingPrice: String?
    let listingType: String
    let listingUse: String
    let listingSqft: String?
    let listingBedsCount, listingBathsCount, listingParkingSpot: Int?
    let listingDescription: String
    let featureListing: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case name, image
        case userAddress = "user_address"
        case id
        case listingImage = "listing_image"
        case listingVideo = "listing_video"
        case listingTitle = "listing_title"
        case listingAddress = "listing_address"
        case listingPrice = "listing_price"
        case listingType = "listing_type"
        case listingUse = "listing_use"
        case listingSqft = "listing_sqft"
        case listingBedsCount = "listing_beds_count"
        case listingBathsCount = "listing_baths_count"
        case listingParkingSpot = "listing_parking_spot"
        case listingDescription = "listing_description"
        case featureListing = "feature_listing"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

The fields searched are listingprice,listingtype,listinguse,listingaddress.

The search filter for each fields is as follows:

```
let list1 = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter { $0.listingAddress!.range(of: keyword!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
let list2 = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter { $0.listingType.range(of: type, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
   
let list3 = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter { $0.listingUse.range(of: use, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
             
let list4 = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter {
            if let price = Int($0.listingPrice ?? "0") {
                return (price > min! && price < max!)
            }
            return false
        }
```

Now to get the combined search result of all four are as given:

```
let a = list1!.filter { list2!.contains($0) && list3!.contains($0) && list4!.contains($0)}
```

The problem is it is combining the `list1` with `list2` and `list3` and it is showing result properly,

```
let a = list1!.filter { list2!.contains($0) && list3!.contains($0) }
```

,but when i add the `list4` too, the result is zero.

Could someone help me how to combine all the search and get a result which has all the four search field satisfied.

Comment: You don't need to combine 4 lists. Just filter 1 time using all the conditions.

Comment: how to do that?basically i need the common elements of all 4 filter results.

Comment: Maybe this https://pastebin.com/T0rBJkqe ?

Comment: Maybe the search in list 4 is broken.

Comment: @Larme which one to use?there are two methods given

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is search result individually but when combined with other three,it is showing zero result

Comment: I used one with your previous code combined in one, and another with extension on Datum to have clearer code. Use which one you want. `let filtered` is `let a`.

Comment: @Larme tried this code.even this is showing zero result.it has got to do something with the price.the list4 search filter.

Comment: @Larme yes i got it,but my issue is still the same.i want to know the issue as to why it is not considering the price search and not combining it with other search filters?

Comment: Print listingPrice. That might be the culprit

Comment: My guess is that listingPrice contains a decimal value

Comment: listingprice is a string

Comment: I am talking about the content of the string of course

Comment: Those contains a alphanumeric values like $23,CAD57,please call,contact etc.these are the few values.

Comment: I think this condition of if let price = Int($0.listingPrice ?? "0") is failing,because when there is a integer it is showing the Int of that value,but anything other than that it is showing nil.

Comment: Then you need to sort out how to properly handle your price field because until you have done that you will not make any progress with your filtering attempts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223764/discussion-between-saranya-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: @Larme you are right.The price is a string,hence when converted to int,many values are nil and hence even though it is compared with other fields,but since this is nil.it shows nil value.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your struct to Hashable and implement the methods

```
struct Datum: Codable,Equatable, Hashable {
   func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(userID)
        hasher.combine(name)
        hasher.combine(image)
        //Add other values too
    }
}

let result = Set(list1 ?? [])
    .intersection(list2 ?? [])
    .intersection(list3 ?? [])
    .intersection(list4 ?? [])

let array = Array(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that loose the order?

Comment: Yes, when you add elements to set, order is not preserved. On what criteria do you need your list to be sorted.

Comment: @udbhateja are you asking me for the order?

Comment: @saranya Updated the answer, please check.